# How can I provide mocked services for development (not testing) in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I need a way to mock my services during development (not during testing) in Angular 2. The reason being is that the REST-ful server is not reliable (changing API without notification, not stable, and difficult to wipe and stand up again). It would be nice if I can just mock my services (which are all basically HTTP REST clients).

What's the best approach for creating mock backend services in Angular 2? I get a lot of internet results for mocking backend services with respect to testing, but this context is not my use-case (I am not mocking to test but to develop).

I've used the [angular cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) to create and scaffold my project and I'm not sure if that tool can help out.

I'm looking for an approach like [Spring](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html) where we can annotate components/classes with "profiles" and then conveniently specify which profile is active to get the right dependencies injected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the best approach to achieve your goal is to use interfaces and a service provider. I hope the following example code can point you in the right direction:

**data-tables.service-interface.ts**

```
export interface DataTablesServiceInterface {
    getHeaders(): Promise<any[]>;
    getData(query?: string, offset?: number, size?: number): Promise<any>;
}
```

**data-tables.service-provider.ts**

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { OpaqueToken } from '@angular/core';

import { DataTablesServiceInterface } from './data-tables.service-interface';
import { DataTablesService } from './data-tables.service';
import { DataTablesMockService } from './data-tables.mock-service';

import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

let dataTablesServiceFactory = (http: Http) => {
    var serviceToReturn: DataTablesServiceInterface;
    if (environment.production) {
        serviceToReturn = new DataTablesService(http);
    } else {
        serviceToReturn = new DataTablesMockService();
    }
    return serviceToReturn;
};

export let dataTablesToken = new OpaqueToken('DataTablesServiceInterface');

export let dataTablesServiceProvider =
    {
        provide: dataTablesToken,
        useFactory: dataTablesServiceFactory,
        deps: [
            Http
        ]
    };
```

You just need to implement the actual and mock service and can provide them depending on the embedded profile mechanism already implemented in angular-cli by use of `environment`.

**Edit:**
There are a few more information I forgot to mention. In your responsible module you need to declare `dataTablesServiceProvider` as provider. In the components where you want to use the service, the approach of DI varies slightly from the standard approach.

In the constructor of the component you write the following:

```
constructor(@Inject(dataTablesToken) private dataTablesService: DataTablesServiceInterface)
```

If you are interested in opaque tokens, I would suggest a look at [Opaque Token by Angular](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OpaqueToken-class.html)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but this adds the mock including test data to the production output bundle