# Angular2 Extend Service

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to extend a existing angular service (in this example `Http`).

**Requirements:**

- The service extension is handled via angulars dependency injection
- It should be possible to extend the service multiple times (for example in a way the [Decorator Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) allows it)
- The generated object must implement (if possible) or extend the `Http` so that existing code does not need to be changed. The DI injects the "decorated" `Http`.
- One possible use case would be a `Http` "decorated" by `SecureHttp` and `LoggingHttp`.

**What I tired so far:**

- `SecureHttp implements Http` does not seem to work because 1. `Http` is no interface and 2. it has protected members that need to be implemented
- Extend Http

  ```
  class SecureHttp extends Http {
    constructor(_backend: ConnectionBackend, _defaultOptions: RequestOptions, private _http: Http){
      super(_backend, _defaultOptions);
    }

    get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
      console.log("This is secure Http.");
      return this._http.get(url, options);
    }
  ...
  }
  ```

  But I don't know how to provide the service so `Http` gets injected by `SecureHttp` class but `Http` in `SecureHttp` gets injected by `Http`.

**Am I on the right track?**

Or are there other concepts in angular2 that allow the extention of existing services that I don't know of?

Comment: You might want to check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39675806/how-to-extend-angular-2-http-class-in-angular-2-final), it might contain what you are looking for.

Comment: @alexkucksdorf the question you are referring to seems to cover the basic extension of a service, but not the requirement to extend it with multiple independent implementations.

Comment: You could make use of conditional provision in your factory. I implemented something similar in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41852212/how-can-i-provide-mocked-services-for-development-not-testing-in-angular-2/41852498#41852498) for mocked services.

Comment: Why do you need the basic Http in your `SecureHttp extends Http` example? You could just call `super.get(...)` instead of `this._http.get(...)`.

Comment: check the implementation of [AuthHttp in angular2-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt/blob/master/angular2-jwt.ts)

Comment: @JánHalaša My plan was to use the Decorator Pattern to, for example allow allow custom logging and security on top of the Http basic functionality.

Comment: @OferHerman AuthHttp is a independent implementation which - as far as I understand it - can not inject the angular Http service. This would mean that all Http references in the project need to be replaced by the new implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this specific issue there is a solution with the new [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) you can use [HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) to extend requests before they are beeing sent.

An article with explainations can be found at [medium.com](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8).