# Angular 4 - get parent Component to choose a service that children will use

Tags: angular

I have an instance of four different services, `DataSourceCsv1Service`, `DataSourceCsv2Service`, `DataSourceXml1Service` and `DataSourceXml2Service`. I'm trying to create a `DataSource` Component with buttons/links/radio buttons/some way so that the user can choose which of these services should be used for any children Components displayed in the `DataSource` Component.

I've added these services to the providers in `app.module.ts`:

```
....
providers: [ DataSourceCsv1Service, DataSourceCsv2Service, DataSourceXml1Service, DataSourceXml2Service ],
....
```

and the children Components should use the parent Component selection to pull their data. However, I'm not sure how to choose from the providers supplied to the parent Component, so that only one source is used.

Does anyone have any insight?

Comment: The first approach you could embrace is to use a service provider, like I explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41852212/how-can-i-provide-mocked-services-for-development-not-testing-in-angular-2/41852498#41852498). However, if you need to change the services after initialization of the child component, you might want to consider passing the services as `Input()` variables.

Answer (score 1):

The option using @Input() it is not bad. In my opinion might better than the one I am propousing. However, it is good to have more than one option. The idea is to get your children in the parent and set the service you want in them.

```
export class Parent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild(ChildComponent)
  private child: ChildComponent;

  @ViewChild(AnotherChildComponent)
  private anotherChild: AnotherChildComponent;

  constructor(
    private _dataSourceCsv1Service: DataSourceCsv1Service, 
    private _dataSourceCsv2Service: DataSourceCsv2Service, 
    private _dataSourceXml1Service: DataSourceXml1Service,
    private _dataSourceXml1Service: DataSourceXml2Service) { }

  public ngOnInit() {
   this.child.setService(this._dataSourceCsv2Service)
  }
```